# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 26161

Tags: kotlin

### kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dbName has not been initialized

IM STILL NEW TO KOTLIN , AND I NEED YOUR HELP TO INITIATE THIS VARUABLE

```
               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 26161
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dbName has not been initialized
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3116)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3259)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1950)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
                                                                                                    Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dbName has not been initialized
                                                                                                        at com.example.myapplication.Database.databaseHelper$Companion.getDbName(DatabaseHelper.kt:52)
                                                                                                        at com.example.myapplication.Database.databaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.kt:10)
                                                                                                        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3259) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1950) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
2023-05-26 20:12:47.563  1555-2805  ActivityManager         system_server
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

}

class databaseHelper(context: Context, dbname: String) :
SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dbName, null, 1) {
private val mComntext: Context
private var mDatabase: SQLiteDatabase? = null

```
package com.example.myapplication.Database

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import com.example.myapplication.G


class databaseHelper(context: Context, dbname: String) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dbName, null, 1) {
    private val mComntext: Context
    private var mDatabase: SQLiteDatabase? = null

    init {
        dbName = "$dbname.db"
        TBL_NAME = "laws"
        mComntext = context
    }

    override fun onCreate(sqLiteDatabase: SQLiteDatabase) {}
    override fun onUpgrade(sqLiteDatabase: SQLiteDatabase, i: Int, i1: Int) {}
    fun openDatabase() {
        val dbPath = mComntext.getDatabasePath(dbName).path
        if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase!!.isOpen) {
            return
        }
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
    }

    fun closeDatabase() {
        if (mDatabase != null) mDatabase!!.close()
    }

    val laws: ArrayList<stractLaws?>
        get() {
            var stractLaws: stractLaws? = null
            val arrayListLaws = ArrayList<stractLaws?>()
            openDatabase()
            val cursor = mDatabase!!.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TBL_NAME, null)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                stractLaws = stractLaws(cursor.getString(1))
                arrayListLaws.add(stractLaws)
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
            cursor.close()
            closeDatabase()
            return arrayListLaws
        }

    companion object {
         lateinit var dbName: String
        lateinit var TBL_NAME: String
        @JvmField
        val DBLOCATION = "/data/data/" + G.context!!.packageName + "/databases/"
    }

}
```

}

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.myapplication.Adapter.lawsAdapter
import com.example.myapplication.Database.databaseHelper
import com.example.myapplication.Database.stractLaws
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.OutputStream

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var arrayList = ArrayList<stractLaws?>()
    var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
        val mDbHelper = databaseHelper(this@MainActivity, "Sanad")
        val database = applicationContext.getDatabasePath(databaseHelper.dbName)
        if (!database.exists()) {
            mDbHelper.readableDatabase
            if (!copyDatabase(this@MainActivity)) {
                return
            }
        }
        arrayList = mDbHelper.laws
        adapter = lawsAdapter(arrayList)
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        listView.adapter = adapter
    }

    fun copyDatabase(context: Context): Boolean {
        return try {
            val inputStream = context.assets.open(databaseHelper.dbName)
            val OutFileName = databaseHelper.DBLOCATION + databaseHelper.dbName
            val f = File(OutFileName)
            f.parentFile.mkdirs()
            val outPutStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(OutFileName)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var length = 0
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
                outPutStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
            outPutStream.flush()
            outPutStream.close()
            true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            false
        }
    }
}

class databaseHelper(context: Context, dbname: String) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dbName, null, 1) {
    private val mComntext: Context
    private var mDatabase: SQLiteDatabase? = null

    init {
        dbName = "$dbname.db"
        TBL_NAME = "laws"
        mComntext = context
    }

    override fun onCreate(sqLiteDatabase: SQLiteDatabase) {}
    override fun onUpgrade(sqLiteDatabase: SQLiteDatabase, i: Int, i1: Int) {}
    fun openDatabase() {
        val dbPath = mComntext.getDatabasePath(dbName).path
        if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase!!.isOpen) {
            return
        }
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
    }

    fun closeDatabase() {
        if (mDatabase != null) mDatabase!!.close()
    }

    val laws: ArrayList<stractLaws?>
        get() {
            var stractLaws: stractLaws? = null
            val arrayListLaws = ArrayList<stractLaws?>()
            openDatabase()
            val cursor = mDatabase!!.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TBL_NAME, null)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                stractLaws = stractLaws(cursor.getString(1))
                arrayListLaws.add(stractLaws)
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
            cursor.close()
            closeDatabase()
            return arrayListLaws
        }

    companion object {
         lateinit var dbName: String
        lateinit var TBL_NAME: String
        @JvmField
        val DBLOCATION = "/data/data/" + G.context!!.packageName + "/databases/"
    }

}
```

``